# Log File Parser in Java

Tags: java, database, performance, parsing, design-patterns

I am trying to design Log File Parser for my application. I have thousands of Log files having same pattern of data and my objective is to first parse the data and store it in a database.
Log file has following pattern-

```
a=some_value_1 b=some_value_2 c=some_value_3 d=some_value_4
a=some_value_5 b=some_value_6 c=some_value_7 d=some_value_8
a=some_value_9 b=some_value_10 c=some_value_11 d=some_value_12
a=some_value_13 b=some_value_14 c=some_value_15 d=some_value_16
```

My initial idea is to read all the files line by line using `InputStreamReader` and for every file in every line pick the data and fetch it to db. Seems good for some files but performance wise i need to improve my design. Can somebody suggest some better design model/architecture for the same?

Comment: Default Java IO is not known as fast...

Comment: What are your constraints? How many records, how many files? For example, if you have enough memory, you could just map the files to memory...

Comment: can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: just did a quick check - using a BufferedReader, as gkuzmin suggests, should be as fast as memory-mapping the files; and it is simpler

Comment: @tucuxi It's not known as slow either.

Comment: @EJP - many contestants in ACM's ICPC avoid Java just because of IO overhead. Yes, in this case there should be no problem. But it is still hard to compete with C's fgets + sscanf: simple yet powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that it will be better to use `BufferedReader` instead of `InputStreamReader`. The parsing part of your task does not seem very hard now.

Comment: Any specific design pattern for this?

Comment: I had some similar task in the past. I used BufferedReader and it was great. Another part of your application is concluded in DB interaction. In my case my colleague wrote stored procedure that accepted a xml file with fixed format and put it into DB table.Then DB job woke up and parse it to distinct table for log records. Actually reading and parsing of log files was fast enough (few hundreds of MB per second), but DB server was really slow in xml parsing. So, you can think about stored procedure to avoid multiple inserts.

Comment: But aware of stored procedure slowness. Generally this kind of tasks is simple enough and has no cornerstones. So, I do not know any concrete pattern which I can propose you to solve this problem.

Comment: yes. you are right. so what you did to speed up db? and what you will suggest me for db operations?

Comment: I did nothing to speed up DB. It was my colleague's part. Actually my program was used to monitor server logs and it was very rare situation when huge xml file, produced by my program, was sent do db. So nobody cares. :) I can advise you to discover your particular DB capabilities - may be it is perfectly suited for xml parsing? Maybe not. Maybe it is not necessary to use xml in your case and you can try to use another format. Maybe JSON will be better, for example. DB performance may vary a lot for different tasks, vendors and versions so it is better to try something or browse docs/Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns are great, but you should use them only when they make sense. No special pattern required here: just iterate over the files; for each file, read it, and do the inserts as required. The program should not take up more than 50 lines in a single file/class with a main[] method. Small, clean code is much better than complex, large code.