# Log file parser - count invocations

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

My scenario is to find - count of invocations of a specific method which is called on a condition.

Every invocation of the method makes a entry into log file with a combination of static + dynamic content.

So with the help of static text, I need to parse the log file(very massive) and find the count.

Is there any tool available for this ? I know a java program using reader would do the job(as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784032/log-file-parser-in-java)), but searching for a existing tool / way to do.

Thanks !!

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to do this manually, use grep and wc on the command line. (If you need this to run automatically or be invoked from a program you'll have to explain a bit more about the situation)